# Artichoke wilts at midday

Tags: sunlight, shade, wilt

I have a new 3 foot tall artichoke plant in a roomy pot on my sunny deck in zone 17.  If I leave it in full sun, it wilts by midday.  Can I keep it in semi-shaded area and expect it to bud?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Can you tell us where you live, or what the temperature range is? I can't seem to fine a zone 17 on the map. My zone maps only go up to 13. Do you have a picture of your plant you can post? It would be nice for us to be able to see it, and the pot it's in! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[image: baby artichokes in unheated green house zone 1B]Perhaps.  How large is this pot? If it is less than 10 gallon pot forget it.  I'd get your artichoke in a larger amount of potting soil in at least a 10 gallon pot and make sure you water very deeply.  Potting soil, not garden soil. That is another story you don't want to be rewriting.  Why aren't you planting this guy in the garden?  You plant is simply not getting enough water probably because the pot is too small or you are using garden soil in a pot instead of potting soil that gets so compacted it will not absorb water.  The water simply exits on the sides of the soil between pot and soil.  Potting soil for all plants in pots or pot like situations such as enclosed raised beds.  These artichokes did not last through the winter as the greenhouse wasn't heated well enough.  But these are in garden soil.  Not potted.  Everything that is planted in a pot should be in potting soil, not garden soil.  Otherwise the garden is a far better place to plant your artichoke. When plants are grown for flowers or fruit, sunlight is critical.  The more energy a plant gets from the light, the more energy it has to make flowers and fruit.  Shade will always hamper the plants ability to make food for itself and enough energy to make seed and fruits.

Try up potting your artichoke into a larger pot with potting soil (really, too cheap and the only way to grow anything in a pot)  In your zone, an artichoke is a perennial, will come back every year IN THE GARDEN.  You shouldn't have to water every single day.  In partial shade???  Well, have you got any artichokes started?
[image: baby artichokes zone 1B in an unheated greenhouse[![][1]]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8VFE.jpg)